# Yellow scrollbars in Chrome when using the jQuery's fadeIn() method

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, visualization

I am trying to make a modal window that will appear after a link is clicked. Initially a mask is shown to fill up the whole screen and after that the modal window is shown using the jQuery's fadeIn() method. It is working perfectly well in FF, Opera, Safari and even in IE (with some minor remarks :). However the problem is that during the visualization process the scrollbars in Chrome appear in different colors such as yellow, red and black before getting full visible. Is there a way to avoid this from happening?

My html code is:

```
<a href="#dialog" name="modal">Simple Window Modal</a>

<div id="dialog">
    <div id="file"><div style="height:500px;"></div></div>
</div>

<div id="mask"></div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$().ready(function() {

    $('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var id = $(this).attr('href');

        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();

        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

        $('#mask').fadeIn(500);
        $('#mask').fadeTo("fast", 0.9);

        $('#mask').show();

        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();

        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

        $(id).fadeIn(500);

    });
});
```

The result:

[black scrollbar in Google Chrome http://www.strangerstudio.net/demo/chrome-scrollbars-1.png](http://www.strangerstudio.net/demo/chrome-scrollbars-1.png)

With some content:

[yellow scrollbar in Google Chrome http://www.strangerstudio.net/demo/chrome-scrollbars-2.png](http://www.strangerstudio.net/demo/chrome-scrollbars-2.png)

Thanks a lot!

Edit:
Probably this unwanted effect cannot be avoided at the time since even the popups with scroll-bars in chrome://chrome/settings/ have it.

Comment: How to prevent the Chrome firework during the visualization? :)

Comment: how about fading the contents rather than the box itself?

Comment: ... and what about the box, will it be visible the whole time? Here is a demo to try it for yourself:
http://www.strangerstudio.net/demo/modal-window/modal-window.html

Comment: You could just use `.show()` on the box, and `.fadeIn()` on the contents.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, you probably won't find a workaround. Proper approach would be to post a report about this on the [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines) tracker.